# How to sum of count from 2 queries in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 2 tables called `NotificationEvent` and `NotificationEventLog` in SQL with the same structure.

I have 2 queries that select `EventCount` group by `Month` for each table:

First query for `NotificationEvent`:

```
SELECT MONTH(CreationDate) Month, COUNT(*) AS EventCount
FROM NotificationEvent
WHERE YEAR(CreationDate) = 2020
GROUP BY YEAR(CreationDate), MONTH(CreationDate)
ORDER BY YEAR(CreationDate), MONTH(CreationDate)
```

Output:

```
Month   EventCount
-----------------
3      | 10
4      | 20
5      | 30
6      | 40
```

Second query for `NotificationEventLog`:

```
SELECT MONTH(CreationDate) Month, COUNT(*) AS EventCount
FROM NotificationEventLog
WHERE YEAR(CreationDate) = 2020
GROUP BY YEAR(CreationDate), MONTH(CreationDate)
ORDER BY YEAR(CreationDate), MONTH(CreationDate)
```

Output:

```
Month   EventCount
-----------------
1      | 5
2      | 15
3      | 25
4      | 35
5      | 45
6      | 55
```

What I need is `Sum` of event count of those output as shown below. I tried to use [`UNION`](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_union.asp) but that does not work as I expected.

```
Month   EventCount
-----------------
1      | 5  ==> It comes from NotificationEventLog 
2      | 15 ==> It comes from NotificationEventLog
3      | 35 ==> Sum of NotificationEvent and  NotificationEventLog (10 + 25)
4      | 55 ==> Sum of NotificationEvent and  NotificationEventLog (20 + 35)
5      | 75 ==> Sum of NotificationEvent and  NotificationEventLog (30 + 45)
6      | 95 ==> Sum of NotificationEvent and  NotificationEventLog (40 + 55)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One method is a `full join`:

```
SELECT COALESCE(ne.Month, nel.Month) as month,
        (COALESCE(ne.EventCount, 0) + COALESCE(nel.EventCount, 0))
FROM (SELECT MONTH(CreationDate) as Month, count(*) AS EventCount
      FROM NotificationEvent
      WHERE YEAR(CreationDate) = 2020
      GROUP BY YEAR(CreationDate), MONTH(CreationDate)
     ) ne FULL JOIN
     (SELECT  MONTH(CreationDate) Month,count(*) AS EventCount
      FROM NotificationEventLog
      WHERE YEAR(CreationDate) = 2020
      GROUP BY YEAR(CreationDate), MONTH(CreationDate)
     ) nel
     ON ne.month = nel.month;
```

Comment: Thanks it worked as expected. I will keep the question as open a bit more to get different approaches.

Answer (score 1):

Use CTE to get both sum and individual sum

```
;with cte_a as(
SELECT  MONTH(CreationDate) Month,count(*) AS EventCount
FROM NotificationEvent
WHERE YEAR(CreationDate) = 2020
GROUP BY YEAR(CreationDate),MONTH(CreationDate)
), cte_b as(
SELECT  MONTH(CreationDate) Month,count(*) AS EventCount
FROM NotificationEventLog
WHERE YEAR(CreationDate) = 2020
GROUP BY YEAR(CreationDate),MONTH(CreationDate)
), cte_month as (
Select distinct month from cte_a
Union
Select distinct month from cte_b
)
Select
M.month
, coalesce(a.eventcount, 0) as EventCount
, coalesce(b.eventcount, 0) as EventLogCount
, coalesce(a.eventcount,0) + coalesce(b.eventcount,0) as EventTotalCount

From cte_Month as m
Left join cte_a as a on a.month = m.month
Left join cte_b as b on b.month = m.month
order by m.year
```

Comment: It throws an exception  `The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, subqueries, and common table expressions, unless TOP, OFFSET or FOR XML is also specified.`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `UNION ALL`.

```
SELECT MONTH, SUM (COALESCE (EVENTCOUNT, 0))
    FROM (  SELECT MONTH (CREATIONDATE) MONTH, COUNT (*) AS EVENTCOUNT
              FROM NOTIFICATIONEVENT
             WHERE YEAR (CREATIONDATE) = 2020
          GROUP BY YEAR (CREATIONDATE), MONTH (CREATIONDATE)
          --order by  YEAR(CreationDate),MONTH(CreationDate)
          UNION ALL
            SELECT MONTH (CREATIONDATE) MONTH, COUNT (*) AS EVENTCOUNT
              FROM NOTIFICATIONEVENTLOG
             WHERE YEAR (CREATIONDATE) = 2020
          GROUP BY YEAR (CREATIONDATE), MONTH (CREATIONDATE)--order by  YEAR(CreationDate),MONTH(CreationDate)
         ) T
GROUP BY MONTH
ORDER BY 1
```

Comment: It throws an exception: `'NVL' is not a recognized built-in function name.`

Comment: My bad. Sql server does not support it. Edited my answer.

Comment: I am still getting an exception : `Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'FROM'.`

Comment: Edited again. I hope this one will work correctly. @SelimYıldız

Comment: Give a name to the union after the closing bracket, i.e. )  t group by month ... or use a CTE, with union_query as (...) select month, sum(eventcount) group by 1 order by 1. No need to coalesce, the union query does not produce nulls. @ismetguzelgun - Oracle is hard to forget, right?